# Get current query record field in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a search results form that has text boxes that are populated by data from multiple queries. I do not want to use subforms, so form/control binding is (I believe) an impossibility. Instead, I'm trying to directly access the relevant query row field and increment the row field using

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataQuery, "My query name", acNext, 1
```

whenever a button is pressed. However, this method seems to only let me access the first record in the query, as setting the text box value to

```
"My Query name".Fields("Desired Field")
```

only gives me the first record's result. My next step was trying to use Recordset navigation using this code

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Base_FH_Qry")
'DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataQuery, "Base_FH_Qry", acNext, 1
[Forms]![Search_Results_Flat_Code_Frm]![CBT_FH].Value = rs.Fields("comm_amt_ati")
rs.MoveNext

End Sub
```

This causes me to re-open the Recordset every time the button is clicked, so it doesn't help me either.

My specific question is, which, if any, of these methods (Multiple bound queries to form, directly access query fields, or Recordset navigation) are viable and what do I need to change in my approach to get them to work? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I made a query out of the multiple queries and used this new query as the control source for the form. I then set each text box's control source appropriately.